# JuliaLang: ERROR: LoadError: IOError: open(“..)

Tags: julia, packagecompiler.jl

I am trying to generating executable. So, I created Net module inside .Net/src/Net.jl. However, when I run `packagecompiler.jl` (below), it gives an error. How can I solve the problem?

```
module Net

using NativeFileDialog, JLD2, Parameters

Base.@ccallable function julia_main()::Cint
  try
    netlisttranslator()
  catch
      Base.invokelatest(Base.display_error, Base.catch_stack())
      return 1
  end
  return 0
end

#=
Here all sub-functions called by netlisttranslator()
netlisttranslator()
=#
```

`packagecompiler` is:

```
using PackageCompiler: PackageCompiler, create_sysimage, create_app, create_library
using Pkg
ENV["JULIA_DEBUG"] = "PackageCompiler"
Pkg.activate("$(@__DIR__)")
Pkg.add("PackageCompiler")
Pkg.add("NativeFileDialog")
Pkg.add("JLD2")
Pkg.add("Parameters")
Pkg.resolve()
Pkg.instantiate(; verbose = false)
tmp_app_source_dir = "$(@__DIR__)"
app_compiled_dir = "$(@__DIR__)\\generated"
create_app(tmp_app_source_dir, app_compiled_dir; incremental=false, force=true,
                       executables=["Net" => "julia_main"
                                    ])

Activating environment at `c:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
    Updating registry at `C:\Users\amroa\.julia\registries\General`
    Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Manifest.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Manifest.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Manifest.toml`
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Manifest.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Project.toml`
  No Changes to `C:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\Manifest.toml`
PackageCompiler: bundled artifacts:
  ├── ATK_jll - 2.219 MiB
  ├── Bzip2_jll - 2.232 MiB
  ├── Cairo_jll - 13.579 MiB
  ├── Expat_jll - 1.125 MiB
  ├── Fontconfig_jll - 3.017 MiB
  ├── FreeType2_jll - 4.737 MiB
  ├── FriBidi_jll - 570.671 KiB
  ├── GTK3_jll - 73.302 MiB
  ├── Gettext_jll - 19.930 MiB
  ├── Glib_jll - 20.546 MiB
  ├── Graphite2_jll - 696.780 KiB
  ├── HarfBuzz_jll - 6.257 MiB
  ├── JpegTurbo_jll - 4.951 MiB
  ├── LERC_jll - 758.367 KiB
  ├── LZO_jll - 1.084 MiB
  ├── Libepoxy_jll - 13.043 MiB
  ├── Libffi_jll - 205.667 KiB
  ├── Libgcrypt_jll - 6.433 MiB
  ├── Libgpg_error_jll - 2.227 MiB
  ├── Libiconv_jll - 2.245 MiB
  ├── Libtiff_jll - 9.779 MiB
  ├── NativeFileDialog_jll - 474.944 KiB
  ├── PCRE_jll - 4.222 MiB
  ├── Pango_jll - 4.738 MiB
  ├── Pixman_jll - 5.945 MiB
  ├── Wayland_protocols_jll - 465.663 KiB
ERROR: LoadError: IOError: open("c:\\Users\\amroa\\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\\AmroAlsabbagh\\Code\\Julia\\Tests and Notes\\12- Create exe file\\NetlistEMTP\\Net\\generated\\share\\julia\\artifacts\\f42f9d226c70f0bc88e5f897d914d9de1ac2ce03\\share\\wayland-protocols\\unstable\\fullscreen-shell\\fullscreen-shell-unstable-v1.xml", 769, 33206): no such file or directory (ENOENT)
Stacktrace:
  [1] uv_error
    @ .\libuv.jl:97 [inlined]
  [2] open(path::String, flags::UInt16, mode::UInt64)
    @ Base.Filesystem .\filesystem.jl:87
  [3] sendfile(src::String, dst::String)
    @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:956
  [4] cptree(src::String, dst::String; force::Bool, follow_symlinks::Bool)
    @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:331
  [5] cptree(src::String, dst::String; force::Bool, follow_symlinks::Bool) (repeats 4 times)
    @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:328
  [6] cp(src::String, dst::String; force::Bool, follow_symlinks::Bool)
    @ Base.Filesystem .\file.jl:353
  [7] cp
    @ .\file.jl:349 [inlined]
  [8] bundle_artifacts(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, dest_dir::String; include_lazy_artifacts::Bool)
    @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\amroa\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\wpsGv\src\PackageCompiler.jl:1124
  [9] create_app(package_dir::String, app_dir::String; executables::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, precompile_execution_file::Vector{String}, precompile_statements_file::Vector{String}, incremental::Bool, filter_stdlibs::Bool, force::Bool, c_driver_program::String, cpu_target::String, include_lazy_artifacts::Bool, sysimage_build_args::Cmd,
 include_transitive_dependencies::Bool)
    @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\amroa\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\wpsGv\src\PackageCompiler.jl:699
 [10] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\packagecompiler.jl:25
in expression starting at c:\Users\amroa\OneDrive - polymtl.ca\AmroAlsabbagh\Code\Julia\Tests and Notes\12- Create exe file\NetlistEMTP\Net\packagecompiler.jl:25
```

Comment: What is the content of `packagecompiler.jl`? And do you just run `julia packagecompiler.jl`? Did you try to run every line in a Julia REPL so that you can pinpoint the error?